# Round function is not working

Tags: c#

I have a float value like 45.25214

I want to make it take (or round) just two numbers after the comma. I tried this:

```
sl = sl / count;
Math.Round(sl, 2);
```

But the result is not changing; it's still the same.

Comment: You have to reassign it to your variable.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I already tried that but I got that I can't convert double to float

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.Round` is a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), so you need to use its return value for it to be useful.

```
sl = sl / count;
sl = Math.Round(sl, 2);
```

Comment: That is not working. I got that I can't convert double to float

Comment: Cast to float: `s1 = (float)Math.Round(s1, 2)`

Comment: `sl = (float)Math.Round(sl, 2)`, then. `Math.Round` works on doubles, not singles, so when you pass a single it casts it to a double, and the return value of that overload is a double.

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning the rounded value to the original variable.
Also, you should cast it to float.

```
sl = sl / count;
sl = Math.Round(sl,2) as float;
```